# Set value boolean in symfony and update

Tags: symfony, boolean, setvalue

I trying to set the value of boolean during update. but return error.

Here is the entity.

```
/**
 * Set status
 *
 * @param boolean $status
 * @return CongressStaffer
 */  
public function setMailStatus($status)
{
    $this->status = $status;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get status
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getMailStatus()
{
    return $this->status;
}
```

$staffer->setMailStatus();

$em->flush();

Answer (score 1):

What kind of error did you get?

**Also,** you need to pass a value to your setter,

```
$staffer->setMailStatus(true); // Or false
```

**Or,** define a default value in you setter,

```
public function setMailStatus($status = false) // Or true
{
    // ...
}
```